# Introduction to spectral graph theory

Tags: reference-request, spectral-graph-theory

What are the basic references? Are there any good, high-level surveys of SGT and its applications to CS in general and machine learning more specifically?

Answer (score 19):

Two sources: The [Fan Chung book on spectral graph theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821803158)  and [Dan Spielman's notes](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/sgta/) on the same.

Answer (score 15):

There is a new upcoming book on [Spectral Algorithms](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vempala/spectralbook.html) by Ravi Kannan and Santosh Vempala covering several latest developments. It covers several applications of spectral methods, algorithms for estimating spectral parameters and low rank approximation of matrices.

Answer (score 12):

I really like [L. Lovász: Random walks on graphs: a survey](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/erdos.pdf)

Answer (score 10):

Beside Fan Chung's book, I also like [Biggs'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521458978); it's short and sweet. I heard that [Cvetković-Doob-Sachs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3527296859) is supposed to be encyclopedic but I haven't had a chance to check it out yet. Yes, I agree with Ryan than Lovasz' survey is a pleasure to read (so do most of his surveys).

Comment: I have seen Cvetković-Doob-Sachs and agree that it is encyclopedic. Lots of examples worked out. Expensive though...

Answer (score 9):

Godsil and Royle's Algebraic Graph Theory is a good book too, though it has more than just spectral graph theory.

Answer (score 0):

I found this lecture note to be of great help [Michael W. Mahoney](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04845.pdf)